# Import JSON using MagicalRecord

Tags: ios, iphone, json, magicalrecord

I have this JSON document:

```
    [
  {
  "category": "Para los invitados",
  "items": [
            {
            "title": "Invitaciones",
            "subtitle": "Sobres, imprenta",
            "items": [
                      "Invitaciones",
                      "Sobres",
                      "Coste envío invitaciones",
                      "Tarjetas de agradecimiento",
                      "Sobres para tarjetas de agradecimiento",
                      "Coste de envío tarjetas de agradecimiento"
                      ]
            },
            <three elements more...>
            ]
  },
<two elements more...>
]
```

How can I import this document using MagicalRecord ? Can anyone paste an example ?

Thanks!

Comment: Yes, but I need some help to create the relationships (userInfo properties in the CoreData model?). Can you help me ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have finished a Core Data Model and included Magical Record, you can parse the JSON File:

```
// Your Json File
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"YOUR_JSON"];
NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL: url];

NSError *error; // For later error handling

NSDictionary* json = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

// Json values for "items" key
NSDictionary *items = [json valueForKey:@"items"];

// We are going through the items
for(int i = 0; i < [items count]; i++) {

    // We save the title values into our CoreData Model

    NSManagedObjectContext *localContext = [NSManagedObjectContext MR_contextForCurrentThread];

    NSString *title = [[items valueForKey:@"title"] objectAtIndex:i];

    YOUR_MODEL_ENTITY *entity = [YOUR_MODEL_ENTITY MR_createInContext:localContext];

    entity.title = title;

    // We save it
    [localContext MR_saveToPersistentStoreWithCompletion:^(BOOL success, NSError *error) {
                    if (error) {
                        NSLog(@"Couldn't save new title with Magical Record: %@", error);
                    }
                }];
}
```

I hope that it's right, what I wrote...
Please have a look on the [documentation](https://github.com/magicalpanda/MagicalRecord/tree/develop/Docs) :)